# Cant disable Indexes in Apache HTTP

Tags: apache, http, server

I am trying to set up an virtual Host with Apache HTTP Server,everythings works fine except that i cant disable Indexes in my httpd.conf file.

What i have :
In my httpd.conf

```
    <Directory />
       Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

In my httpd.vhosts.conf

```
<Directory ****>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I thought `-Indexes` would remove the "index-of" and would instead show my html-file.

Hope someone can help me out with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options):

> Note Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid
>   syntax and will be rejected during server startup by the syntax check
>   with an abort.

So in other words you cannot have:

```
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

But must instead have this syntax to alter the existing Options settings:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI
```

Or this syntax to just overwrite the existing Options settings:

```
Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

However I'm confused why you think you need "-Index" as you have not specified that in you main httpd.conf, so it should not be generating the index pages anyway in your vhost sub location?